# How to configure encrypted SQL Server connections to prevent MITM attacks?

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, sql-server-2016

It has come to my surprise that SQL Server by default does nothing to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks when configuring your SQL Server to enforce connection encryption.

Forcing encryption on your connections is dead-simple. You go to Sql Server Configuration Manager, expand SQL Server Network Configuration, Protocols for [your instance], right-click TCP/IP, change Force Encryption to 'Yes', restart SQL Server and you're done.
[image: Force Encryption set to Yes]

Per Microsoft TechNet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067(v=sql.105).aspx), this will generate a Self-Signed Certificate. Fine, no problem, **But I expect my clients to complain that the certificate is not trusted.**  However, they do not. They happily connect to it. I then realize that 'Trust server certificate' **is checked by default in SQL Management Studio**. Fine, but the most shocking realization is: **even if you uncheck "Trust server certificate", SSMS does not complain, warn, or reject the connection.**

[image: Trust server certificate is unchecked]

So by default SQL Server is completely susceptible to MITM attacks because clients do nothing to verify the certificate from SQL Server. The certificate shouldn't have to be signed by a CA: the certificate should have to be configured as a trusted certificate on the client. If that's not true, what is the "Trust server certificate" checkbox for?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question, really. This is more server configuration. Try the DBA site or serverfault, maybe.

Comment: Moved: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147642/how-to-configure-encrypted-sql-server-connections-to-prevent-mitm-attacks

Comment: What happens when you setup a virgin system with trust unticked? Maybe it had already added the server cert or ca cert to its trust list.

Comment: @symcbean I thought the same thing- I connected to it from a virgin system, same thing happened.

Answer (score 1):

See [Using Encryption Without Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131691.aspx). Aside from the connection setting 'Trust Server Certificate', there is another setting, the *client* setting 'Trust Server Certificate', which is configured from the Configuration Manager. If *any* of the two is set, a self-signed certificate will succeed (actually is a bit more complex as the client setting `No` will override the connection setting... see the link).

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2016 versions ship with TLS  1.0 to TLS 1.2 support ([Transport Layer Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)).

TLS 1.0, 1.1  and SSL 3.0 should be disable, and use only TLS 1.2 for client-server communication.

(other versions of SQL servers is supported with TLS 1.2 by CU cumulative update )

SQL server use a protocol named TDS as an application layer over TCP. No known vulnerabilities have been reported for the Microsoft TDS implementation.

Because several standards-enforcement organizations are mandating the use of TLS 1.2 for encrypted communication channels, Microsoft is releasing the support for TLS 1.2 for the widespread SQL Server installation base.

review: [TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244)

**Is SQL Server Prevent MITM attacks (Man In The Middle)**

The certificate authority system is designed to stop the man-in-the-middle attacks. In TLS, the SQL server uses the private key associated with their certificate to establish a valid connection and encrypt all traffic over wire. 
The server keeps the key secret, so the man-in-the-middle can’t use the SQL server real certificate;

**Using of self signed certificates :**

The use of self signed certificates is never acceptable in production environment but may be used in test environment.
Use SHA256 signed certificate/chain, SHA1 is becoming obsolete.

You can apply the rules related to Server certification described in [Transport Layer Protection Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet)

Windows administrators can enable TLS 1.2 support for Windows O.S to get benefit of TLS 1.2

For your point:

*SQL Server by default does nothing to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks when configuring your SQL Server to enforce connection encryption.*

Security is a policy managed by a security policy written document and implemented by Administrators of O.S/Database/Network/Application... and audited.

Is  SQL server  compliant to the Security standard? 
The Answer is yes. Recently ALL old SQL servers 2008/2012 is becoming TLS 1.2 support with CU.

**Conclusion:**

- Organizations should avoid using self assigned Certification in production Environment and use CA certifications.
- DBA /Windows/Network Admin can implement TLS 1.2 for SQL server/Windows and network infra structure.
- Connection String in application can support Encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* this was due to a bug in the ODBC driver, which is now fixed with a big breaking change in the ODBC 18 driver see [ODBC 18 Driver release article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228).
The Trust option was ignored if Encrypt=no was specified in the client connection string.